# Setting up Azure DevOps as mirror cannot resolv certain plugins

Tags: maven, azure-devops

We are trying to setup Azure DevOps cloud as our only end point when we are building our java artifacts through maven. We have set-up our feeds and created a single feed that will work as mirror for Maven Central Repository. When building the artifacts all dependencies are fetched without any issue. The problem starts when we are trying to invoke certain plugins e.g. the versions plugin. When we invoke it we get:

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'versions' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/airmil/.m2/repository), centralCloud (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/...)]

It happen also with other plugins such as help plugin but others seem to work fine e.g jaxws. When we remove the mirror configuration from the settings.xml everything works fine. We haven't extensive tested with plugins work and which don't.

The configuration of the feed is the default allowing upstream sources from the ones set default by Azure DevOps cloud.

[image: feed configuration for Upstream Sources]

Any ideas what cause this issue

Comment: Could you please share the command you  are using?

Comment: What you will get when running `mvn help:system`?

Comment: The command I am using is mvn versions:set or mvn help:effective-pom. As mentioned before with mvn help I get the same error 
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'help' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/airmil/.m2/repository), centralCloud (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/...)]